# How to change views within the same screen (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, tabbar, react-native

I want to duplicate the following with react-native-scrollable-tab-view:

[image: ezgif com-video-to-gif]

Currently my code is the following, but I am not sure how to execute and incorporate the module to make things easier - does anyone have any ideas on how I can implement this? (I am a novice so any help is appreciated):

**This is the main (tab view):**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
var Restaurants = require('../Helpers/Restaurants');
var More = require('../Helpers/More');
var api = require('../Api/Api');
var Profile = require('../Helpers/Profile');
var Recipes = require('../Helpers/Recipes');
var Actions = require('react-native-router-flux').Actions;
var Home = require('../Helpers/Home');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image, 
  TabBarIOS,
  Component
} = React;


class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'home',
      notifCount: 0,
      presses: 0,
    };
  }

  GoBack() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS 
        tintColor="#49B64D"
        barTintColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
          icon={require('image!homeicon')}
          onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                  selectedTab: 'home',
              });
          }}>
            <Home/>
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'restaurants'}
          icon={require('image!nomicon')}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'restaurants',
                });
          }}>
          <Restaurants/>
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
       <Icon.TabBarItem
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'recipes'}
          icon={require('image!haticon')}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'recipes',
                });
          }}>
          <Recipes/>
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
          icon={require('image!accounticon')}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'profile',
                });
          }}>
          <Profile/>
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: window.width,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});

module.exports = Main;
```

**This is the recipes view when you click on the recipes tab:**

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var Seperator = require('./Seperator');
var api = require('../Api/Api');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var LinearGradient = require('react-native-linear-gradient');
var Swipeout = require('react-native-swipeout');
var List = require('./List');
var RecipeDetails =  require('./RecipeDetails');
var Actions = require('react-native-router-flux').Actions;


var {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ListView,
  NavigatorIOS,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5,
    opacity: 0.9,
    height: window.width,
  },
  dietText: {
    color:'white',
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next', 
    alignSelf:'center',
  },
  title: {
    textAlign:'left', 
    marginTop: (window.width/1.4), 
    fontSize: 20, 
    color: 'white', 
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next', 
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  dietbuble: {
    backgroundColor:'transparent', 
    height:20, 
    width:60, 
    borderRadius: 10, 
    backgroundColor:'#49B64D',
    marginRight:5,
  },
  nombtn: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    marginBottom: 5,
  }, 
  arrow: {
    height: 15,
    width: 15,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
  }, 
  upvotenum: {
    marginRight: 5, 
    fontSize: 20, 
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next'
  }, 
  dish_num: {
    backgroundColor:'#49B64D',
    height: 30,
    width: 100,
    marginLeft: window.width/1.36,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  dishtext: {
    fontFamily: "Avenir Next",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "400",
    textAlign: 'center',
    color:"white",
  },
  profilebubble: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
    margin: 2,
  }
});

var list = [
  {
    component: <List/>
  }
]

class Recipes extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      venues: new Object(),
    };
  }

  activateHome() {
    api.getAnything(this.props.paleo,this.props.vegan,this.props.vegetarian,this.props.healthy,this.props.dairyfree,this.props.nutfree,this.props.glutenfree)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });
  }

  detailsRecipe() {
    this.props.navigator.push ({
        component: RecipeDetails,
        title: "",
    })
  }

  render(){ 

    return (
      <ScrollView
        alwaysBounceVertical={true}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}>
        <Swipeout right={list}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.huffpost.com/gadgets/slideshows/404432/slide_404432_5031844_free.jpg'}} style={{width: window.width, height: window.width}}>
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginBottom: 100,}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/02/kate-600.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00851/82ef9ae8-ae34-11e4-_851122b.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'transparent', '#1C1C1C']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.recipedetails} underlayColor='transparent'>
                          <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: window.width, marginTop:-20}}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Name | 10 Mins</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginTop: -75}}>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegan</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegie</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: window.width/3, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                             <Text style={styles.upvotenum} >20</Text>
                             <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('image!upvotearrow')}></Image>
                             <Image style={styles.nombtn} source={require('image!nombtn')}></Image>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                      </LinearGradient>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
        <Seperator/>
        <Swipeout right={list}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.funkinutt.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Vegan-Scallops-Sophies-Kitchen.jpg'}} style={{width: window.width, height: window.width}}>
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginBottom: 100,}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/02/kate-600.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00851/82ef9ae8-ae34-11e4-_851122b.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'transparent', '#1C1C1C']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.recipedetails} underlayColor='transparent'>
                          <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: window.width, marginTop:-20}}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Name | 10 Mins</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginTop: -75}}>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegan</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegie</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: window.width/3, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                             <Text style={styles.upvotenum} >20</Text>
                             <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('image!upvotearrow')}></Image>
                             <Image style={styles.nombtn} source={require('image!nombtn')}></Image>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                      </LinearGradient>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
        <Seperator/>
        <Swipeout right={list}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'http://m5.paperblog.com/i/37/370315/guest-blogger-vegan-richa-samosa-and-onion-bh-L-KmHfF4.jpeg'}} style={{width: window.width, height: window.width}}>
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginBottom: 100,}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/02/kate-600.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00851/82ef9ae8-ae34-11e4-_851122b.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'transparent', '#1C1C1C']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.recipedetails} underlayColor='transparent'>
                          <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: window.width, marginTop:-20}}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Name | 10 Mins</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginTop: -75}}>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegan</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegie</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: window.width/3, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                             <Text style={styles.upvotenum} >20</Text>
                             <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('image!upvotearrow')}></Image>
                             <Image style={styles.nombtn} source={require('image!nombtn')}></Image>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                      </LinearGradient>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
        <Seperator/>
        <Swipeout right={list}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.choosingraw.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IMG_8328.jpg'}} style={{width: window.width, height: window.width}}>
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginBottom: 100,}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/02/kate-600.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                        <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00851/82ef9ae8-ae34-11e4-_851122b.jpg'}} style={styles.profilebubble}/>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'transparent', '#1C1C1C']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.recipedetails} underlayColor='transparent'>
                          <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: window.width, marginTop:-20}}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Name | 10 Mins</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginTop: -75}}>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegan</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={styles.dietbuble}>
                              <Text style={styles.dietText}>Vegie</Text>
                           </View>
                           <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: window.width/3, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                             <Text style={styles.upvotenum} >20</Text>
                             <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('image!upvotearrow')}></Image>
                             <Image style={styles.nombtn} source={require('image!nombtn')}></Image>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                      </LinearGradient>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
        <Seperator/>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
};


module.exports = Recipes;
```

**And this is the recipe details view:**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var LinearGradient = require('react-native-linear-gradient');
var Tabbar = require('react-native-tabbar');
var Item = Tabbar.Item;
var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Component, 
  Image, 
  ScrollView, 
  TouchableHighlight,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  }, 
  venue_image: {
    width: window.width, 
    height: window.height/4, 
    flex: 1, 
  }, 
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    opacity: 0.9,
    height: window.height/3.7, 
  },
  title: {
    textAlign:'left', 
    fontSize: 15, 
    color: 'white', 
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next', 
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  nombtn: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    marginBottom: 5,
  }, 
  arrow: {
    height: 15,
    width: 15,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
  }, 
  upvotenum: {
    marginRight: 5, 
    fontSize: 20, 
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next'
  }, 
  dietbuble: {
    backgroundColor:'transparent', 
    height:20, 
    width:60, 
    borderRadius: 10, 
    backgroundColor:'#49B64D',
    marginRight:5,
  },
  submenutext: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '600', 
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    marginTop: 10,
  }, 
  undernum: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: '400', 
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center', 
  }, 
  units: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir Next',
    fontSize: 10,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }
});

class VenueDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'ingredients',
    };
  }

  _Directions() {
    this.setState({selectedTab: 'directions'});
    console.log(this.state.selectedTab);
  }

  _Nutrition() {
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'nutrition'});
     console.log(this.state.selectedTab);
  }

  _Ingredients() {
    this.setState({selectedTab: 'ingredients'});
    console.log(this.state.selectedTab);
  }

  makeBackground(btn){
    var featurebox = {
     flex: 1,
     height: window.width/4,
     width: window.width/3,
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center',
    }
    if(btn === 0 || btn === 2){
      featurebox.backgroundColor = '#49B64D';
    } else if (btn === 1){
      featurebox.backgroundColor = '#585858';
    } 
    return featurebox;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.huffpost.com/gadgets/slideshows/404432/slide_404432_5031844_free.jpg'}} style={styles.venue_image}>
              <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'transparent', '#1C1C1C']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', marginTop: window.height/4.3}}>
                   <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', marginRight: window.width/4, marginLeft: 10}}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Name | 10 Mins</Text>
                   </View>
                   <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                     <Text style={styles.upvotenum} >20</Text>
                     <Image style={styles.arrow} source={require('image!upvotearrow')}></Image>
                     <Image style={styles.nombtn} source={require('image!nombtn')}></Image>
                    </View>
                </View>
               </LinearGradient>
            </Image>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
            <TouchableHighlight 
              onPress={this._Ingredients.bind(this)}
              style={this.makeBackground(0)}
              underlayColor='transparent'>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.submenutext}>Ingredients</Text>
                <Text style={styles.undernum}>5</Text>
                <Text style={styles.units}>Count</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight 
               onPress={this._Nutrition.bind(this)}
               style={this.makeBackground(1)}
               underlayColor='transparent'>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.submenutext}>Nutrition</Text>
                <Text style={styles.undernum}>200</Text>
                <Text style={styles.units}>Sugars</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight 
              onPress={this._Directions.bind(this)}
              style={this.makeBackground(2)}
              underlayColor='transparent'>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.submenutext}>Directions</Text>
                <Text style={styles.undernum}>10</Text>
                <Text style={styles.units}>Hours</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = VenueDetails;
```

**Currently, all of this looks like this:**
[image: ezgif com-optimize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was missed feature of react-native-router-flux (to switch between 'tabs' within one container) and I've added it recently, please check latest version.

You need to use Container element and define your routes inside it. Also you have to define TabBar implementation to use with that container (check Example with its TabBarFlux)

Comment: Please provide example?  Where is example TabBarFlux ?  I cannot figure out how to combine react-native-router-flux with a react-native-tabs. I get nothing displayed.

Comment: 0.22 is supported version now. Example contains tab bar.

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is I'd create an array of objects with each object representing the different views/components in your footer slider thing. Then, have a property on your state which is the active tab and when a user clicks on a new tab, update the active tab to be whatever the new index is. What we're going to do is, whatever the active tab is, grab that specific component that you had in the tabMap you made above and render it. The code will look something like this.

```
var tabMap = [
  {key: 0, icon: 'ion|ios-contact-outline', state: 'bio', asArray: false, Component: About},
  {key: 1, icon: 'ion|ios-paper', state: 'posts', asArray: true, Component: Posts},
  {key: 2, icon: 'ion|ios-people', state: 'friends', asArray: false, Component: Friends},
  {key: 3, icon: 'ion|ios-heart', state: 'activity', asArray: false, Component: Activity},
];
```

So that represents that different tabs in the lower section.

```
getInitialState(){
   return {
      activeTab: 0
   }
}
```

That's my initial state which is going to keep track of which tab I'm on.

Then in my render method I grab the component of the current active tab,

```
var BodyComponent = tabMap[this.state.activeTabIndex].Component;
```

Now that I have the component, I can simply render BodyComponent passing in whatever data I would like.

```
 <BodyComponent
    header={tabMap[this.state.activeTabIndex].header}
    authedUser={this.props.authedUser}
    isGuest={this.props.isGuest}
    userToRender={this.state.userToRender}
    data={this.state[tabMap[this.state.activeTabIndex].state]} />
```

Comment: This is really cool. I've tried doing this, and worked for me.